# python, replace if/elif with dictionary

Tags: python

Folks,
  How would you rewrite the if/elif in the 'checkme' function with a dictionary?

```
def dosomething(queue):
    ...

def checkme(queue):
  """ Consume Message """
  if queue == 'foo':
    username = 'foo'
    password = 'vlTTdhML'
  elif queue == 'bar':
    username = 'bar'
    password = 'xneoYb2c'
  elif queue == 'baz':
    username = 'baz'
    password = 'wnkyVsBI'
  ...
  dosomething(queue)

def main():
    checkme('foo')
    checkme('bar')
    checkme('baz')
```

Comment: Can you clarify: is the call to `dosomething` supposed to *always* happen after the entire `if` block finishes? Or is it supposed to execute only in the case that the `if` statements based on `queue` all fail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
passwords = {'foo':'vlTTdhML', 'bar':'xneoYb2c', 'baz':'wnkyVsBI'}
username, password = queue, passwords[queue]
```

The above assumes that there's a password in the dictionary for every user. If that's not the case, better play it safe and use this:

```
username, password = queue, passwords.get(queue, None)
```

Either way, you can simply call `dosomething(queue)` at the end. As currently stated in the question, `dosomething` is always invoked.

Comment: Fails to address the request to call `dosomething(queue)` upon `queue` being a missing key.

Comment: @EMS that's not stated in the question, the question is simply asking how to replace `if/elif` with a dictionary. Look again at the code in the question, the `dosomething(queue)` call is performed at the end, it doesn't matter if `queue` was missing - in fact, it'd be a simple matter to just copy-paste the call to `dosomething` after my code. Please reconsider the downvote.

Comment: @EMS and while you're at it, consider removing the downvote on this question, as it is (with the information available), it's unjustified, it seems you misinterpreted the original question

Comment: I thought I was clear. If the OP intended the `dosomething()` call to happen as an `else` block in case `queue` wasn't in the `dict` of username/password pairs, then I do think your answer deserves a downvote. The way the question is written, it's not clear to me whether the OP did or did not intend that, so I asked for clarification. If the OP clarifies that `dosomething` should have *always* executed after the `if`/`else` block no matter what `queue` is, then I'll undo the downvote and vote to close the question as a duplicate.

Comment: @EMS so in your worldview, I'm "guilty until proven innocent", with you being the judge of it. That's not how most people in StackOverflow think, oh well. I'm not continuing with this discussion, my time is better spent elsewhere.

Answer (score 6):

You could do something like this:

```
CHECK_ME = {'foo': 'vlTTdhML', 'bar': 'xneoYb2c', 'baz': 'wnkyVsBI'}

def checkme(queue):
    username, password = queue, CHECK_ME.get(queue)
    #May be some more check here, like
    if not password:
        print 'password is none'
        #Or do something more relevant here

    #rest of the code.
```

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you're relying on side-effects, especially with the `dosomething(queue)` part, so I'll assume that is all handled OK in my solution, but I'd prefer to do it in a way that did not rely on side-effects.

```
def checkme(queue):

    class to_do_dict(dict):
        def __missing__(self, itm):
            dosomething(itm)

    to_do = to_do_dict({
        "foo":("foo", "v1TTdhML"),
        "bar":("bar", "xneoYb2c")})

    username, password = to_do[queue]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

> {'foo': {'username': 'foo', 'password': 'vlTTdhML'}}

And just keep adding dictionaries as you'd like.

Answer (score 1):

Nested dictionaries would do the trick.

To set the usernames and passwords:

```
queue = {}

queue["foo"] = {"username": "foo", "password": "vlTTdhML" }
queue["bar"] = {"username": "bar", "password": "xneoYb2c" }
```

And to check whether the username/password exists:

```
if queue.get("foo"):
 username = queue["foo"]["username"]
 password = queue["foo"]["password"]

else:
 # username does not exist, so do something
 print "username does not exist"
```